# skip openssh-server configuration on apt-get upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, apt, linode

When I'm trying to upgrade Ubuntu 20.10 on Linode, it stucks on one configuration prompt.
How can I skip it?
Using -qy didn't help, as shown below.

The code:

```
set DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get update -qy
apt-get upgrade -qy -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: From the man page, options are before the main command (`apt-get *options* upgrade`)

Comment: Thank @Chris. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: I would try with `export DEBIAN...` instead of `set`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71144